# Python: Raise exception but not from sub functions

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Is it possible in Python, to catch an exception at the current function level, but not from called sub functions?

Please consider this example:

```
def func(some_dict):
    print(some_dict["special_value"])

some_dict = {
    "general_value": True,
    # "special_value": True
}

try:
    if some_dict["general_value"]:
        func(some_dict)
except KeyError:
    print("General value not set")
```

I would like to catch the KeyError that `if some_dict["general_value"]:` might throw, but raise any KeyErrors from within `func(...)`

However, the example above will show `General value not set` although the key `general_value` is set.

I can think of the following workaround, but I'm wondering if there's a better way

```
temp_value = None

try:
    temp_value = some_dict["general_value"]
except KeyError:
    print("General value not set")

if temp_value: 
    func(some_dict)
```

Another way to ask this question: Is it possible to exclude certain parts within a `try/except` block from being caught?

Comment: Your workaround is the correct way to do this.

Comment: An alternative is to catch `KeyError` inside `func`, then throw a more specific application-defined exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround is the right general idea, but can be done more neatly as:

```
try:
    some_dict["general_value"]
except KeyError:
    print("General value not set")
else:
    func(some_dict)
```

or perhaps:

```
if "general_value" in some_dict:
    func(some_dict)
else:
    print("General value not set")
```

which seems a little clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a nested try/except - but this is not recommended.

```
try:
    if some_dict["general_value"]:
        try:
            func(some_dict)
        except KeyError:
            print("special error")
except KeyError:
    print("general value not set")
```